# Identify time gap in large data

Tags: r, time, apply, intervals

I'm working on a function to identify a gap in a series of start/end dates. The output should be FALSE if a start date begins later than 1 day after any of the previous end dates.

DATA:

```
df <- data.frame('ID' = c('1','1','1','1','1','1'), 'start' = as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-09','2010-02-01', '2010-02-10')),
                 'end' = as.Date(c('2010-01-03', '2010-01-22', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-12', '2010-02-10', '2010-02-12')))
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
  ID      start        end  continuous
1  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-03 FALSE
2  1 2010-01-03 2010-01-22 TRUE
3  1 2010-01-05 2010-01-07 TRUE
4  1 2010-01-09 2010-01-12 TRUE
5  1 2010-02-01 2010-02-10 FALSE
6  1 2010-02-10 2010-02-12 TRUE
```

This code gets the desired result on this small dataset:

```
df$continuous <-
  sapply(split(df, df$ID),
                function(x) {
                  lapply(1:nrow(x),
                         function(y) {
                           any(x$start[y] - x$end[-(y:NROW(x$end))] <= 1)
                         })
                })
```

However, applying this to a bigger set (>100,000 observations) with many different IDs it still creates wrong output. Example:

```
 ID         start       end            continuous
 2    2015-01-15   2015-01-15             FALSE
 2    2015-01-16   2015-01-17             TRUE
 2    2015-01-16   2015-01-17            FALSE #wrong, should be TRUE
 2    2015-01-17   2015-01-19             TRUE
 2    2015-01-20   2015-01-22             TRUE
 2    2015-01-22   2015-01-23            FALSE #wrong, should be TRUE
 2    2015-01-26   2015-01-26             TRUE
 2    2015-01-26   2015-01-30             TRUE
 2    2015-01-26   2015-01-26            FALSE #wrong, should be TRUE
 2    2015-02-01   2015-02-06             TRUE #wrong, should be FALSE
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: `?lead` from `dplyr` might be helpful here.

Comment: Already tried this but overlapping periods jump observations so      lead doesn't work.